# rspec says that No route matches but the route works in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem is so simple i do not have any clue of what could be wrong.

I have this spec:

```
it "/fr/admin/articles/new" do
  expect(:get => "/fr/admin/articles/new").to route_to(:controller => 'articles', :action => 'new')
end
```

**when i browse localhost:3000/fr/admin/articles/new it works !**

but my test says:

```
Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/fr/admin/articles/new").to route_to(:controller => 'articles', :action => 'new')
   No route matches "/fr/admin/articles/new"
   # ./spec/routing/articles_routing_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

my routes.rb:

```
scope '/:locale', :constraints => LocaleConstraint do
  root :to => 'static#home'
  scope '/admin' do
    root :to => 'articles#index'
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

also my locale_constraint.rb

```
class LocaleConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    /(fr|zh)/.match(request.path_parameters[:locale])
  end
end
```

output of rake routes:

```
    ckeditor        /ckeditor                                  Ckeditor::Engine
       admin        /admin(.:format)                           :controller#:action
       login GET    /login(.:format)                           sessions#new
      logout GET    /logout(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
    sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                        sessions#create
        root        /:locale(.:format)                         static#home
        root        /:locale/admin(.:format)                   articles#index
    articles GET    /:locale/admin/articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /:locale/admin/articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /:locale/admin/articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /:locale/admin/articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /:locale/admin/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PUT    /:locale/admin/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /:locale/admin/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root        /                                          :controller#:action

Routes for Ckeditor::Engine:
        pictures GET    /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#index
                 POST   /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#create
         picture DELETE /pictures/:id(.:format)         ckeditor/pictures#destroy
attachment_files GET    /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#index
                 POST   /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#create
 attachment_file DELETE /attachment_files/:id(.:format) ckeditor/attachment_files#destroy
```

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's a bug in Rails, see:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8679